# “to be in a shape of” or “to have a shape of” dinosaur

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, idioms, phrases

Which phrase, if any, of the following, is correct with regard to **each single element** of my puzzle design:

1. element **has** a shape of a dinosaur
2. element **is in** the shape of a dinosaur
3. element **is of** the dinosaur shape
4. **is dinosaur-shaped**

[image]

**My research.**

I find support for "have a shape" in texts related to geometry. Here is an example:

https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_do_we_mean_by_shape_and_when_do_two_objects_have_similar_shapes

Here is scientific work in which the phrase "is a shape of" is frequently repeated:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c824/a5c28db61405b19412a1fed6a2a8dc5733d4.pdf

Update for bounty.

I would like to find a compromise between brevity and precision. I want to point out that the puzzles are different from ordinary jigsaw puzzle in which each element is a rectangle with tabs and blanks.

- I do not want to be as simple as to say that each element is a dinosaur (which is simple but not precise, since piece of wood is not an animal).
- I do not want to be too descriptive as to say that it is a caricature of dinosaur or artistic impression of a dinosaur, which is precise but not simple.
- I would like to avoid ambiguity. The figure is meant to be a dinosaur, not a dinosaur-like creature.

The best solution would be a two-three word phrase for layman audience.

Comment: I could have sworn you had asked this question (with identical picture) before, though I can't find it. (2) and(4) are both idiomatic ways of saying it.

Comment: @KateBunting yes, I did. I asked it at English Language and Usage. I received a few valuable comments there which I have saved. But my question was soon closed as off-topic without leaving a comment why. I tried to improve it but it ended up only with down vote. Apparently the threshold was too high for me there.

Comment: (2) is more formal, (4) more colloquial. People sometimes say informally, of something or someone they miss very much "There is a (--)-shaped hole in my life."

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me, and appears self-contradictory. I don't mean this as blame or disparagement, but to try to encourage you to decide if you might get better answers by changing it. First, you ask what "is correct". What do you mean? Grammatical? To designate something correct or incorrect requires some standard. What that could be here is unclear. You do not give us the context in which the word or phrase would be used. To me, I'm afraid the answers and comments in them, so far, betray the problems and not only that, they make them worse. Finally, you've put a bounty 1/

Comment: on the question, thus preventing what seems to me probably needs to happen: Voting for the question to be closed, explaining why, and giving you the opportunity to rephrase it in a way that's likely to be helpful. EDIT: Further, asking "which is correct, 1, 2, 3, or 4?" seems to imply that you do not want any additional options. Yet your question also seems to request them. Quite problematic. 2/2

Comment: @JimReynolds Thank you. I will be happy to correct my question. Do you mean I should clarify (1) whether I want a statement which communicates the shape of the piece with emphasis how this piece is different from the regular jigsaw puzzle (rectangle with tabs and blanks), or (2) whether any of the four alternatives are grammatically correct? The first case, of course. The alternatives I have presented are mere guesswork that should give you a clue of what I want to achieve. Naturally I was eager to learn other alternatives so I wrote if either is correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another stack exchange community or elsewhere if it solicits writing advice or marketing communications advice more than a question about English. If it does belong here, it needs more context: Describe what to who in what sort of genre for what purpose? In addition, the language, in both the question and comments, is vague and confusing. Complex phrases and “big” words are used, but with poor control of English—a problematic combination.

Comment: Don't be overly concerned Przemyslaw Remin, the people who answered, understood perfectly the question. Your level of English is very advanced, I knew exactly what your request was. Despite your deletion, no one on EL&U complained or voted to close your question where it was first posted. I remember several helpful comments and suggestiond which you took onboard.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wonder if he is really interested in how shapes are described in English. I don't think your answer is much different from mine and the one that got the bounty does seem to fall short on several counts. Go figure....The basic ways to describe shape seem to have been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

"Have the shape of" isn't really the best way of saying what you mean.

If you *have* something that belongs to someone else then you have the actual thing, or it is identical. For example, if someone says "I have my father's nose", it means their nose is identical to their fathers. A wooden toy isn't *exactly* the same shape as a real dinosaur... what you are trying to say is that it is *like*, or *resembles* the shape a dinosaur - recognisably so.

"In the shape of..." is an idiomatic phrase, you'll find it in the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-shape-of-sth), and it means "*in the form of* something, or *appearing as* something". The toy has been made in a particular shape to *appear as*, or *resemble the form of* a dinosaur.

Another idiomatic way to say this would be "it is *shaped like* a dinosaur".

Comment: Is it really so? Tell it to a child that "this toy is not a bear, it is just shaped like a bear". Yes, I am aware it is just a dinosaur silhouette, mere wooden figurine, not a real animal. I want to explain the shapes of my puzzle to layman in simple words. "like dinosaur" sounds as if I failed to achieve the goal. I aim only for good caricatures bearing distinctive traits of real reptiles, I do not aim at creating real reptiles :-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I certainly didn't think I was speaking to a child, nor was I speaking to you as if you were one. Rather, I was explaining why "[x] has the shape of [y]" is not idiomatic. If you *have* something that belongs to someone else then you have the actual thing, or it is identical. For example, if someone says "I have my father's nose", it means their nose is identical to their fathers.

Comment: Thanks. To sum up. You say (1) not idiomatic (improper?), (2) you favor that one, (3) and (4) you didn't address those, you add alternative "is shaped like a dinosaur".

Comment: It is a common behavior that we give names of other things to describe shape. For example "pepper tomato" which is a pepper but HAS/IS_IN the shape of tomato. Isn't it useful human ability to communicate shortly, by approximation with picture. It would be ok for me if someone showed me the picture of a person and said "this is my son." Doesn't the shape have the embedded approximation in its meaning? What's the shape of a tire? A torus? Maybe in outer space, but on earth it is always a little flattened. But people say it's round or circle. It has nothing to do with being a child or adult.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I don't know why you keep bringing children and adults into this. I never mentioned this in my answer. The shape of a tire is a circle. But we wouldn't say "a tire is *in the shape of a circle*", we would say "a tire **is** a circle", because a circle **is** a shape. You could say something is "dinosaur-shaped", but that would be odd when the item **is** meant to be a dinosaur. I've told you what I believe to be the idiomatic way to describe a 2-dimensional toy that is in the shape of a dinosaur, I'm happy to let my answer stand.

Comment: Shaped like a dinosaur or *is dinosaur shaped.*

Answer (score 0):

- The shapes in my puzzle are all **elephant shapes**.
- The pieces of my puzzles are **elephant shaped**. [not before a noun]
- Elephant-shaped pieces are hard to fit together. [dash if before a noun].

In English, **something is or isn't a shape**. In English, we don't usually say: "have the shape of". There is an idiom: x takes the shape of y. But that is separate from this.

- A circle shape, or circle
- A square shape, or square

A circle-shaped canvas [for a painting, for example]
A square-shaped head [for a person or figure of a person, for example]

Answer (score 0):

- **Each** jigsaw **piece**…

We say jigsaw puzzles are made of *pieces*.

- …is **shaped like** a dinosaur

1. We use the copular verb, *like*, to connect the subject (*each jigsaw piece*) to its [predicate nominative](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/predicate_nominative.htm) (*a dinosaur*).

- Each jigsaw piece is **shaped like** a dinosaur

2. The OP could mention that the pieces are *handcrafted*, which is a strong [selling point](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/selling-point). The OP and Lambie's suggestion “dinosaur shaped" works well here

- Each **handcrafted** piece is **dinosaur shaped**

3. We could say the jigsaw puzzle is composed of [animal name] + pieces

- A puzzle made of **dinosaur pieces**.

4. The addition of “wooden“ will dispel any idea that the pieces are made from *real* dinosaur flesh and bone.

- A puzzle made of **wooden** dinosaur pieces

Comment: A similar puzzle can be found here: […*a set of wooden puzzles that are uniquely **shaped like animals** which intertwine with each other to make a puzzle*](https://odditymall.com/unique-wooden-animal-puzzles-for-babies)

Comment: Yeah, intertwine, me old foote. :)